# find a file under multiple directories and copy the files' full paths to created text file

Tags: linux

1) same text file need to be found under multiple directories

```
SUBJ1/*/*/sametext.txt
SUBJ2/*/*/sametext.txt
SUBJ3/*/*/sametext.txt
etc.
```

2) then create a text file and copy all the `sametext.txt` full paths to the new text file. I can only think of using `find`, `grep`, `printf`.

I've tried

```
grep -rl --include="sametext.txt" "searchString" ${PWD}
find . -name "sametext.txt" |grep "filename"
```

Not even give the full paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For paths that do not contain newlines:

```
find "$PWD" -name sametext.txt >full_paths.txt
```